# applying passwords to scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, passwords

For my task, I have a set of 4 scripts, each calls the other. They have to be different scripts for redundancy (however one calls the other). At the moment any script can be run with the bash command. To run the task, I run the first script and then it calls the second and so on.

Is there a way I can apply a password to the second, third and fourth scripts which would only be applied if someone tries to bash them?

so basically no password would be required if I run the first script (and when it calls the other scripts, no password would be required), however if i try to run the second script (or the 3rd or the 4th) it would ask me for a password.

I think I can save a password to a file and call the file fro the 2nd and third script, but is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick a parameter that is likely to be unset. (`PASSWORD_TO_RUN_SUBSCRIPTS` might be a good choice. At the very beginning of your first script, add

```
export PASSWORD_TO_RUN_SUBSCRIPTS=1
```

(the actual value is unimportant, as long as you set it to something).

In each of the subscripts, simply check if `PASSWORD_TO_RUN_SUBSCRIPTS` is set, and exit if it isn't. `bash` parameter expansion provides a useful operator for this:

```
: ${PASSWORD_TO_RUN_SUBSCRIPTS:?Script may only be run from within script1}
```

A more portable version is

```
if [ -z "$PASSWORD_TO_RUN_SUBSCRIPTS" ]; then
    printf "Script may only be run from within script1\n"
    exit
fi
```

If you attempt to run any of the subscripts without giving `PASSWORD_TO_RUN_SUBSCRIPTS` a value, it will exit and print the given message to standard error.

To explicitly run a subscript, you can do something like

```
PASSWORD_TO_RUN_SUBSCRIPTS=1 script2
```

to "trick" `script2` into thinking it is running in the correct environment.

Comment: I like the idea, but i have on question:
is PASSWORD_TO_RUN_SUBSCRIPTS a parent variable which can be used by the child scripts.. or do I have to run it like
PASSWORD_TO_RUN_SUBSCRIPTS=1 script2
all the time (as in enter that at the end of the first script)

Comment: Oh, good point. It does need to be added to the environment of the first script using `export`, rather than simply set. That way, it is inherited by each subscript when launched by the first script. I'll update.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of how you do the password bit (either hardcoding it in the script or a file as you mentioned) the way I can think of to figure out how the script is being called in this case is using $PPID which tells you the pid of the parent process, you can then use that pid to do a PS and figure out if the name of the caller is correct ( as opposed to the shell ) and then decide if asking for a password is required.

Hope this Helps shed some light on the situation